# How to dispose class fields when construction fails?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Let's say I have a class with two fields that each contain disposable objects.

```
    class C : IDisposable {

            private IDisposable thing1 = new Thing1();
            private IDisposable thing2 = new Thing2();

               ... IDisposable implementation ...
    }
```

When creating an instance of class `C` `Thing1` will get created and then `Thing2`.  However, if an exception occurs while constructing `Thing2`, it won't get created and the instance of class `C` won't finish being created either.  The code that was instantiating class `C` doesn't have a reference to the partially constructed `C` to call `Dispose` on it, so we're left with an instance of `Thing1` that never gets disposed.

What's the best resolution?

Comment: Don't run methods that will potentially throw exceptions in situations where you are not equipped to handle them? Not to be glib, but the best solution really is to avoid this problem altogether using a factory method that first attempts to create both disposable objects and then, if successful, passes ownership of the objects to a newly constructed instance of class `C`.

Comment: @dlev: Is there any reasonable way to make factory methods work with inheritance? What's really needed in many cases is a standard paradigm whereby classes could use their constructor to prepare them for connection with the outside world, and then a second method to actually connect them.  Having a factory method invoke the constructor and then call an "initialize" method would be a fine pattern, but for the fact that any given factory method can only construct instances of its own class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the initialization code to the constructor, then wrap the entire constructor in a `try/catch` block that disposes all owned objects and rethrows the exception.

Answer (score 1):

In C++/CLI, it's possible for a single declaration to specify how a field should be defined, initialized, and cleaned up.  In vb.net, it's possible to design a base class such that a subclass will be able to do likewise, e.g.

```
Dim MyBitmap as Bitmap = Acquire(new Bitmap(Params.FileName))
```

where `Params` is an object in which some constructor parameters (like `FileName`) have been stored.  The `Acquire` method (defined in the base class) will add a reference to the newly-created `IDisposable` to a list of things that should be cleaned up if the constructor throws.

Unfortunately, C# does not facilitate either pattern.  The closest one could come would be to define some static methods which use `ThreadStatic` fields to keep track of the created objects, but that would be somewhat icky.  In practice, the best approach is probably to define `Dispose` so as to work correctly with partially-constructed objects, and have every constructor include code like:

```
bool success = false;
try
{
  ...initialize stuff
  success = true;
}
finally
{
  if (!success)
    Dispose();
}
```

Note that because `Dispose()` is virtual, it may get called multiple times.  Additionally, because a subclass `Dispose` method may get called without the subclass constructor having run, every `Dispose` layer needs to be prepared for such a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  Does `Acquire` actually help in the situation when the object never gets fully constructed and thus `Dispose` isn't called?

Comment: @SamuelNeff: It does, if one only calls the constructors through a factory method which checks for the appropriate conditions.  I like the `Acquire` pattern, which I derived from an idea I saw on CodeProject.com, though I'll admit that some of the surrounding code is clunky enough I've not really used it much.  One of the beautiful things about the pattern is that for objects which will encapsulate a fixed set of resources throughout their lifetime, `Dispose` is very easy: `MyDisposeManager.Dispose()` will call `Dispose` on everything that has been `Acquire`d.

Comment: @SamuelNeff: Basically, what needs to happen is that the factory method has to create a `DisposeManager` and pass that to the class constructor (or, for C#, store it in a `ThreadStatic` field).  If construction fails, the factory method can dispose the `DisposeManager`; otherwise, if construction succeeds, the newly-constructed object will dispose it in its `Dispose` method.  I wish C# would allow a class to specify that certain constructor parameters should be available to field initializers (every constructor for the class would then be required to either...

Comment: ...have parameters of the appropriate names and types or chain to a class (not base) constructor that does.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  Sounds neat.  I'll stick with moving initializers to the constructor though, then I can surround in try/catch.  Much cleaner and easier.  Wish I could +1 you again though for coolness of the solution.